# Avoid/fix codeigniter from encoding UTF-8 characters?

Tags: codeigniter, utf-8

Lets take this url:

```
localhost/pradzia/narsyti_krovinius/marsruto_pabaiga/Belebėjus
```

Using the URI class in codeigniter in grab the last segment, using which I want to make a database lookup. However it was failing for me. And couldnt figure out why for ages. But then I tried to output it, and what I got was: `Beleb%C4%97jus` instead of `Belebėjus`. So what I want to is either a way to exclude that particular segment from any filtering by codeigniter, or some function that would give me the original string?

I tried to run it through `utf8_encode()` but it did not work.

So in short:
A: Anyway to exclude a particular instance of uri->segment(n) from whatever filtering codeigniter does?

Or if that not possible:

B: How would I convert the above (or any other string with UTF chars) back to original form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
urldecode( $this->uri->segment(n) );
```

Your html page or http header have to be set with UTF-8 when you display the value.

eg: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Yeah, just found that out. Nevertheless thanks a lot for help! :)